# Postgresql query cast timestamp without time zone adding a second to passed time

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We have a procedure which accepts a timestamp without time zone.

When I pass say
'Sun Dec 03 11:02:19 GMT 2023'

To Postgresql procedure from java by setting date which is java.util.date

The procedure has a cast timestamp with out timezone like
IN run_date timestamp without time zone.

The expected date field value should be
2023-12-03 11:03:19
But
2023-12-03 11:03:20
is stored in db

Why is a second getting added?

We have a logic of fetching the row using the exact date time .so no row is returned because of the seconds mismatch

Comment: First thing to do is to turn on statement logging in postgresql. That way you will know whether your rounding problem is on the java or postgresql side of things (it is almost certainly the java side though).

Comment: Richard....It is happening randomly also we have instances where the sent  time is 11:02:00 and it got saved as 11:02:01.

Comment: It isn't going to be random. It probably is a rounding issue where the value displayed to you by Java isn't the value it is using internally. So it stores `11:03:19.500000001` internally and rounds down on display but when converting rounds up. First thing to do is to make sure you know where the boundary of the problem is.

Comment: So can we round it manually before sending it to Postgresql?

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] that calls the PostgreSQL procedure from Java. Also indicate which Java version you are using, which PostgreSQL version you are using and which JDBC driver you are using.

Comment: Since the resolution of timestamp without timezone is generally microseconds, there should be no reason for 'rounding' a `java.util.Date`, which is only capable of seconds resolution

Comment: I set the milliseconds to 0 manually on Java side and looks like it has fixed the issue.... Will try and do a regression test , just to be sure ... Thank you

Comment: But when are logging date on Java side .it does not log milliseconds Sun Dec 03 11:02:19 GMT 2023'... Else the issue would have been clear

Comment: You should probably be using `java.time`

Comment: @goose must have meant to say “milliseconds” rather than “seconds” in “a java.util.Date, which is only capable of seconds resolution”. Resolution is **milliseconds** in the terribly flawed legacy class `java.util.date`, **microseconds** in Postgres, and **nanoseconds** in the *java.time* classes.

Comment: I have never heard of any date-time rounding being done in any JDBC driver, nor in any database. Truncation in the common way to fit finer values.  I suspect any rounding that occurs must be in your own codebase.

Comment: *@goose must have meant to say* Yes and no Basil. There are actually no methods for milliseconds in `java.util.Date` - only for seconds. But I think this is academic really, since that class shouldn't be being used at all where possible. There's probably crucial missing info from the OP

Answer (score 0):

The Java timestamp you are storing probably has fractional seconds, like `2023-04-01 12:30:00.8888`. Then one of these things can happen:

1. the database column is defined as data type `timestamp(0)`, so PostgreSQL rounds the value up
2. the database column is a normal `timestamp(6)`, and the timestamp is stored as it is, but the program you use to visualize the database contents rounds to seconds

Use a database client that does not lie, like `psql`, and examine the stored values and the table definition.